# How to get auto generated keys of batch insert statement?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I want to INSERT batch of records in a database (i.e. DB2) using JDBC batch statement and then obtain the auto generated IDs of inserted rows. How can I achieve using JDBC API?

Example Code:

```
String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO TABLE1 (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) VALUES (?) ";

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://localhost:900/DATABASE");
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

// first batch
statement.setTimestamp(1, getCurrentTimestamp());
statement.addBatch();

//  second batch
statement.setTimestamp(1, getCurrentTimestamp());
statement.addBatch();

int[] insertedRows = statement.executeBatch();

ResultSet generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
```

The batch statement executes successfully, all rows inserted into database. But when calling `getGeneratedKeys()` to retrieve generated keys, it returns an empty `ResultSet`. Any idea, why?

Comment: It is implementation-dependent if retrieving generated keys is supported on batch execute. JDBC does not require it to be supported.

Comment: Have you tried the variants that use `int[]` or `String[]` to specify the auto-generated columns?

Comment: @Stavr00 Yes, I have tried the variant `int[]` or `String[]` in `PreparedStatement` for batch processing, the `ResultSet` is empty on `getGeneratedKeys()` method.

Comment: You may have to use the `FINAL TABLE` special object to return the inserted elements

Comment: JDBC driver support `getGeneratedKeys()` method otherwise expecting it should throw `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find the db2 specific solution. If the `PreparedStatement` object returns automatically generated keys, call `DB2PreparedStatement.getDBGeneratedKeys` to retrieve an array of `ResultSet` objects that contains the automatically generated keys.

```
import com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2PreparedStatement;
```

// more code here

```
ResultSet[] result = ((DB2PreparedStatement) preparedStatement).getDBGeneratedKeys();

for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    while (result[i].next()) {
        ResultSet rs = result[i];
        java.math.BigDecimal generatedKey = rs.getBigDecimal(1);
        System.out.println("Automatically generated key value = " + generatedKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Still it should be said, the DB2 JDBC Driver devs should hang their heads in shame !!!

Answer (score -1):

```
    objPsmt.executeBatch();
    try (ResultSet rs = objPsmt.getGeneratedKeys()) {
        if (rs != null) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                int generatedId = rs.getInt(1);
                generatedIds.add(generatedId);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception while generating ids ", e);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of what you did ?